# Error in my function

Tags: python, function

When I run my code, I get this error:

```
<function setDegreesAndMinutes at 0x10e7cf6e0>
```

My code is:

```
def setDegreesAndMinutes(self, degrees,minutes):

   self.degrees = int(input())

self.minutes = float(input())

 if(not(isinstance(degrees, int))):


raise ValueError("degrees shoule be int")

if(not(isinstance(minutes(int,float)))):

raise ValueError("minutes shoule be int or float")

 x = degrees 

 y = minutes

 return str(x)+'d'+str(y)

returnValue = setDegreesAndMinutes

print returnValue
```

it will be great, if anyone knows what happened!

Comment: Have you copied your indentation accurately? Are you aware that indentation is important in Python? If so, you should fix your indentation and check/confirm that the problem stays in that case

Comment: I notice that you haven't actually *called* your function, among many other problems.

Comment: @jwpfox: Please don't try to fix the indentation of questions in Python. Also, you took out an important closing parenthesis in your edit.

Comment: thank you all . i am a international student  and this is my first month to study in US,so it took me a long time to figure out what you all said .  Thanks again ,i still  learning

Answer (score 2):

That is not an error at all... You printed a *function object*.

You never *called* the function passing in `(self, degrees, minutes)` as parameters to `setDegreesAndMinutes`.

Also, typically `self` means you have defined that method in a class, so you need an instance of that class to even call `setDegreesAndMinutes`. In which case, you'd need `returnValue = some_class.setDegreesAndMinutes(degrees, minutes)`

Then, do you really *need* parameters? You called `input`, which means you are prompting for values, therefore re-assigning the values that you otherwise would have passed into the method. If you do want to prompt for input from the method, then remove `degrees, minutes` from `(self, degrees, minutes)` and then you can do `returnValue = some_class.setDegreesAndMinutes()`

And finally, setters aren't really necessary in Python, in my opinion. Plus, they usually don't return a value or prompt for input on their own. Make it simple - just *set* the value.

All in all, I think you are looking for something like this

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, degrees, minutes):
        self.degrees = degrees
        self.minutes = minutes

degrees = int(input("degrees: "))

if not isinstance(degrees, int):
    raise ValueError("degrees should be int")

minutes = float(input("minutes: "))

if not isinstance(minutes, (int,float)): # I think you had extra parenthesis after minutes
    raise ValueError("minutes should be int or float")

f = Foo(degrees, minutes)
print(str(f.degrees) + 'd' + str(f.minutes))
```

And if you need to set the values, then do `f.degrees = X` for any `X` value, for example

Comment: First and first , i am so pleasure for you to response my question .    i am a international student without english-speaking environment and this is my first month to study in US,so it took me a long time to figure out what you all said   . i still found a question there , when i run your code , it return "TypeError: setDegreesAndMinutes() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
",  but actually i have not input anything ,i have no chance to input it but get this answer .

Comment: I am able to run this code perfectly fine. Why do you get an error about `setDegreesAndMinutes` when that isn't part of the code I wrote?

Comment: it is still some problems in print the string .  i am trying to handle it ><

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like, but what I've provided runs for me